# Computing a 2D signed distance field

Tags: c#, .net, math, 2d, distance

I'm trying to compute a signed distance field of an black and white images pixels, but I think I've managed to get my code wrong somewhere. As this is my input and output:

Input

[image: Input]

Output

[image: Output]

The issue I'm having is the black line in the middle of the S, my understanding leaves me to believe that it should be completely light gray?

This is the code I'm using:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < source.width; ++x)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < source.height; ++y) 
        {
            // Get pixel
            float a = source.GetPixel(x, y).r;

            // Distance to closest pixel which is the inverse of a
            // start on float.MaxValue so we can be sure we found something
            float distance = float.MaxValue;

            // Search coordinates, x min/max and y min/max
            int fxMin = Math.Max(x - searchDistance, 0);
            int fxMax = Math.Min(x + searchDistance, source.width);
            int fyMin = Math.Max(y - searchDistance, 0);
            int fyMax = Math.Min(y + searchDistance, source.height);

            for (int fx = fxMin; fx < fxMax; ++fx)
            {
                for (int fy = fyMin; fy < fyMax; ++fy)
                {
                    // Get pixel to compare to
                    float p = source.GetPixel(fx, fy).r;

                    // If not equal a
                    if (a != p)
                    {
                        // Calculate distance
                        float xd = x - fx;
                        float yd = y - fy;
                        float d = Math.Sqrt((xd * xd) + (yd * yd));

                        // Compare absolute distance values, and if smaller replace distnace with the new oe
                        if (Math.Abs(d) < Math.Abs(distance))
                        {
                            distance = d;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we found a new distance, otherwise we'll just use A 

            if (distance != float.MaxValue)
            {

                // Clamp distance to -/+ 
                distance = Math.Clamp(distance, -searchDistance, +searchDistance);

                // Convert from -search,+search to 0,+search*2 and then convert to 0.0, 1.0 and invert
                a = 1f - Math.Clamp((distance + searchDistance) / (searchDistance + searchDistance), 0, 1);
            }

            // Write pixel out
            target.SetPixel(x, y, new Color(a, a, a, 1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This method is very inefficient. It is O(n^2). 
You can get better precision and faster solution using a fast marching method: For example that outlined in http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.086/2006/am57.pdf

Answer (score 3):

your culprit is this condition statement:

```
// If not equal a
if (a != p)
{
```

This means that you are only interested on the shortest distance from a Black pixel to a White pixel, or if 'a' is white, then you are looking for the closest Black pixel.

If you change that test to just see:

```
if ( p == white )
{
```

Then you will probably get what you expect.

(I didn't test this, so hopefully its correct).

(Also, if it wasn't correct, it would be nice to post your Math.Clamp method since it isn't a built in library method in the Math class.)

One last thing, not sure if the algorithm wants you to compare a pixel to itself or not, so you might need to account for that within your nested for loops.

(basically, what would you expect the output should look like of an entirely black image with one white pixel in the middle? should the output of the middle pixel be black since there is no nearby white pixels, or should it be white.)